# Write file from exec.Command

Tags: go

I am trying to write a file from a bash command into a file in Go.
Note there are several reasons for using Go over bash here: I have some more logic such as parsing configuration files, I would like to run that code for multiple DBs in parallele and finally performing some more complex data manipulation after.

```
    dumpStr := fmt.Sprintf("pg_dump -U %s -h %s %s | gzip", DbUserName, DbHost, DbName)
    cmd := exec.Command("bash", "-c", dumpStr)
    cmd.Env = append(cmd.Env, "PGPASSWORD="+DbPassword)

    outfile, err := os.Create(DbName + ".gz")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    outfile = cmd.Stdout
    defer outfile.Close()
    err = cmd.Start()
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    cmd.Wait()
```

However, I am getting an emtpy result. 
I am getting data if I am executing `dumpStr` from the CLI but not from that code...
What am I missing?

Comment: Where are you tying the output of the command to your file?

Comment: Also, using `gzip` this way is probably silly. It would be better to use the [gzip](https://golang.org/pkg/compress/gzip/) package.

Comment: Rather than piping to `gzip`, `pg_dump` has built in compression. You can either use `--compress=9` or use the "custom" format `-Fc` which is automatically compressed.

Comment: Come to think of it, `pg_dump` also lets you specify the output file, so there's actually no reason for your go program to get involved _at all_.

Comment: The idea behind using Go is was that I needed to perform this action for a lot of databases

Comment: It may be just me, but what is the exact advantage of doing this compared to `bash -c pg_dump...`?

Comment: @Arkon: Isn't that what bash scripts are for?

Comment: @Flimzy there is more logic behind such as parsing configuration files to retrieve Db credentials for example

Comment: But I agree with you that just looking at that very specific scope, it can (and should) totally be done with Bash only.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Flimzy said, you're not capturing the output of `pg_dump`. You can do that with Go, or you can use `pg_dump`-s `--file`. It can also compress with `--compress` so no need to pipe to `gzip`. Then there's no need for bash and you can avoid shell quoting issues.

```
cmd := exec.Command(
    "pg_dump",
    "--compress=9",
    "--file="+DbName + ".gz",
    "-U"+DbUserName,
    "-h"+DbHost,
    DbName,
)

log.Print("Running pg_dump...")

if err := cmd.Run(); err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
```

Much simpler and more secure.

---

For illustration here's how you'd do it all in Go.

<strike>Use [`Cmd.StdoutPipe`](https://golang.org/pkg/os/exec/#Cmd.StdoutPipe) to get an open IO reader to `pg_dump`'s stdout. Then use [`io.Copy`](https://golang.org/pkg/io/#Copy) to copy from stdout to your open file.</strike>

@Peter points out that since [`Cmd.Stdout` is an io.Reader](https://golang.org/pkg/os/exec/#Cmd) it's simpler to assign the open file to `cmd.Stdout` and let `cmd` write to it directly.

```
// Same as above, but no --file.
cmd := exec.Command(
    "pg_dump",
    "--compress=9",
    "-U"+DbUserName,
    "-h"+DbHost,
    DbName,
)

// Open the output file
outfile, err := os.Create(DbName + ".gz")
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
defer outfile.Close()

// Send stdout to the outfile. cmd.Stdout will take any io.Writer.
cmd.Stdout = outfile

// Start the command
if err = cmd.Start(); err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}

log.Print("Waiting for command to finish...")

// Wait for the command to finish.
if err = cmd.Wait(); err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
```

---

In addition, you're only checking if the command started, not if it successfully ran.

From the docs for [`Cmd.Start`](https://golang.org/pkg/os/exec/#Cmd.Start).

> Start starts the specified command but does not wait for it to complete.
>
> The Wait method will return the exit code and release associated resources once the command exits.

You're checking `cmd.Start` for an error, but not `cmd.Wait`. Checking the error from `cmd.Start` only means the command started. If there is an error while the program is running you won't know what it is.

Comment: StdoutPipe and Copy is silly here. Just assign outfile to cmd.Stdout.

Comment: @Peter Thanks, I thought that all seemed pretty clunky.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this answer. Also, indeed I should make more and better use of pg_dump options.

Answer (score 2):

You need to actually use the output of your command. You're not doing that.  To do so, use the [`StdoutPipe`](https://golang.org/pkg/os/exec/#Cmd.StdoutPipe) method, then you can copy the stdout from your program, into your file.